# Android Socket Client Receiving data

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am creating a basic test application for android that can connect to a socket server and send and receive data. i have been able to get the sending of data from the client to the server working but seem to have a problem getting the android to receive data. the server works as i have been able to test that using a external application.

here is my code

```
package com.socket_sending_and_receving_test;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;



import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Sending_And_Receiving extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;

    String message = "";

    String mClientMsg;

    TextView text;

    final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    int count = 0;

    public static String SERVERPORT;
    public static int SERVERPORT2;
    public static String SERVER_IP;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sending_and_receaving);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText("0");


    }

    Handler myUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setText(mClientMsg);
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    class CommsThread implements Runnable {
        String st = null;
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                Message m = new Message();
                {
                    BufferedReader input = null;
                    try {
                        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                        st = reader.readLine();
                        mClientMsg = st;
                        myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    public void connect(View view) {

        EditText ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip);
        EditText port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
        SERVER_IP = ip.getText().toString();
        SERVERPORT = port.getText().toString();
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        new Thread(new CommsThread()).start();



    }

    public void Disconnect(View view) {

        try {
            socket.shutdownInput();
            socket.shutdownOutput();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ko);
            String str = et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true
            );
            out.println(str);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                SERVERPORT2 = Integer.parseInt(SERVERPORT);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT2);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

after the connection is made the application crashes. I don't think it is due to the UI updating but i think its due to the receiving of data.

here is the logcat

```
07-08 21:59:57.915    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
07-08 21:59:57.920    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
07-08 21:59:57.925    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
07-08 21:59:57.930    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test D/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 10
    User space API version: 10
07-08 21:59:57.930    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test D/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012
07-08 21:59:57.965    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-08 21:59:57.965    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test E/SensorManager﹕ thread start
07-08 21:59:57.970    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42b1cf38
07-08 21:59:58.080    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-08 21:59:58.080    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-08 22:00:03.235    7041-7193/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e792a0)
07-08 22:00:03.240    7041-7193/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2791
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.socket_sending_and_receving_test.Sending_And_Receiving$CommsThread.run(Sending_And_Receiving.java:74)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-08 22:00:03.320    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42b1cf38
07-08 22:00:03.320    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test D/Sensors﹕ Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
07-08 22:00:03.320    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test I/Sensors﹕ sendDelay --- 200000000
07-08 22:00:03.320    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test D/SensorManager﹕ JNI - sendDelay
07-08 22:00:03.320    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test I/SensorManager﹕ Set normal delay = true
07-08 22:00:09.870    7041-7041/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 392 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-08 22:00:11.680    7041-7193/com.socket_sending_and_receving_test I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 7041 SIG: 9
```

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated

Cheers :)

Comment: Any exception thrown?

Comment: it just crashes on the android phone. I.e basicly comes up with the application needs to close.

Comment: You will have a LogCat with errors/exceptions. Please post.

Comment: and i cannot see if any exceptions are thrown

Comment: i have updated the description with the logcat. hope it helps :)

Comment: You have (as you can see) a NullPointerException on line 74 (Sending_And_Receiving.java:74) Please tell us which code line that is.

Comment: that is this line of code

`InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
`

Comment: Then socket will be null. Please check with `if (socket==null)`. Do not start the CommsThread before the connection is established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your socket is NULL. This is because of a race condition:

```
new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
new Thread(new CommsThread()).start();
```

Both threads are started here, but ClientThread will initialise the socket while CommsThread tries to use it. But it is not initialised at this point.

You may call CommsThread's run() right after socket=... or if you really need a 2nd thread, start it there.

Comment: Actually it's the other way around. ClientThread initializes the socket; CommsThread uses it.

Comment: Anyway. Just helping. Using 2 threads, one to open, another for reading is not required, that's true.

Comment: Thanks the fixes the crashing problem :D. Im am very new to android and taking some simple steps to learn :)

Comment: @user3816184 Android doesn't have anything to do with it. The extra thread is a mistake on any platform. Parallelising tasks that must be sequential never makes sense.

Comment: @EJP i understand. i should rephrase that im new to programming, android is sort of my first language. its difficult but its interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

Your CommsThread is running before your ClientThread has completed the connection. So, 'socket' is still null and you get an NPE.

There is absolutely no reason for these to be two different threads. Combine them, so that the connection is made first and then the I/O starts. Using two threads to perform tasks that must be sequential is basically inane.